# ajax not append data on div?

Tags: ajax, append

I dont know what the problem is here, I try to append the content, but its not.

```
var InPro = false;

$(document).ready(function(){
  var form = $('#form32');
  var submit = $('#submit');
  form.on('submit', function(e) {

                       if(InPro) return;
                       InPro = true;

    // prevent default action
    e.preventDefault();

    // send ajax request
    $.ajax({
      url: 'post.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(data){
InPro = false;
        var item = $(data).hide().fadeIn(800);
        $('#post-show').append(data);
        $("#form32")[0].reset();
      },
    });
  });
});
```

and here the post.php:

```
<?php

include_once("config.php");
include_once("verifica.php");

// No direct access to this file
define('IS_AJAX', isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) && strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) == 'xmlhttprequest');
if(!IS_AJAX) {die('Restricted access');}

session_start();

    $user = $_SESSION['user'];
    $comment = $_POST['comment'];

if($comment==""){
die();
}



$ip = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$data = date ("ymdHis");

 $i=mysql_query("INSERT INTO posts (id, foto, user, titulo, youtube, button, data, ip) VALUES ('','0','$user','$comment','$youtube','$button','$data','$ip')");
 $idpostfeed = mysql_insert_id();

 echo"$comment";


?>
```

and my form:

```
<form id="form32" method="post"> <textarea name="comment" id="comment" class="comment" placeholder=""></textarea> <input type="submit" id="submit" class="button" value="Submit Comment"> </form> <div id=post-show></div>
```

so, I want to show result in #post-show div, but it is not working. what is wrong?

thank you!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: can you show us what data is being returned

Comment: Alright so if data is blank that is why nothing is working. What does your php code look like? What is it supposed to return?

Comment: I edit my post, and add the php code!

Comment: So my next question is: What are you trying to do, because there are a few errors in there. One thing you need to change right away is your echo statement, you have it quoted. Change to echo $comment;

Comment: It would also be helpful to see the html of the form you are trying to submit.

Comment: I want to show what user has type on textarea after post.php insert it in sql.

Comment: Are all those variables you are trying to put in the database set?

Comment: yeah, the insert is working!

Comment: thank you! it works now. it was config.php that was included and has an error. really thank you!